# Trying to redirect the user to a new sub

Tags: python

So I'm coming from Visual Basic. Still coding it but learning a bit of python on the side as well. Something i do often in VB is that I can redirect users to a new sub.

```
UserOp = input("What option would you like to do? 1, 2 or 3")

if userop == "1":

    option1()

elif userop == "2":

    option2()

elif userop == "3":

    option3()
```

So the goal here is trying to redirect the user to a new Sub called either 'option1' 'option2' 'option3'.

Thanks i knew this sounds dumb but i just started

Comment: looks like it should work. What is the problem/error you are having?

Comment: well for example. if the user pressed 1. It would redirect them to Option1. So my question is how do i create like a new sub for the option1?

Comment: I think what you mean is a function.
Declared in python with Def.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add that in the question. But yes i know about the 'Def' function. And its just how i can use that to redirect the user to a new Def for example

Comment: If not done already you should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: It is `def`, not `Def` and `def` is **not** a function! Also `UserOp` and `userop` are different variables in Python land because the case matters. You should really follow a basic tutorial on Python to learn about the fundamentals. You will only waste time this way.

Comment: Forget about VB for a bit and learn some Python from scratch - you'll find that some things you remember from VB will help you understand what you're learning, but trying to find one-to-one translations of ideas won't help you. You'll miss out on the things that Python can do that VB can't and you'll develop bad habits in Python that take much longer to unlearn.

Answer (score 0):

So You need to define the function first then you can call them.
I reworked the code :

```
def option1():
    print ("opt1")

def option2():
    print ("opt2")

def option3():
    print ("opt3")

UserOp = input("What option would you like to do? 1, 2 or 3 : ")

if UserOp == "1":
    option1()

elif UserOp == "2":
    option2()

elif UserOp == "3":
    option3()
```

I hope, that's could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way of doing this is to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
def option1():
    print(1)

def option2():
    print(2)

def option3():
    print(3)

switch = {
    "1": option1,
    "2": option2,
    "3": option3,
}

user_option = input("What option would you like to do? 1, 2 or 3")

switch.get(user_option, "Invalid option. Valid values 1, 2, and 3")()
```

The way it works is you map user options to functions using dictionary. In my example, it's called **switch**. Each dictionary key is a user selection, and it points to specific function. After user selects options you call dictionary with **get** method, and the reason for **get**, because it can handle invalid value. Similar to **default:** statement in **switch** statement. The other way of doing it is:

```
switch[user_option]()
```

but this will fail in case if a user enters an invalid entry.